# Umbraco Return All Content (Documents) That I Have Permission to See

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

Is there a way using LINQ to query for all documents that a user has permission to see?  I need to verify against other criteria, but I couldn't find anything specifically dealing with user permissions.

Comment: not in this case, it has to be done through a user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to answer this with the following:

```
string docPermissions = null;
User currentUser = User.GetCurrent();

docPermissions = currentUser.GetPermissions(doc.Path);
if ((docPermissions.Contains("F")) && (docPermissions.Contains("U")))
{
}
```

The permissions explained:

C - Create
A - Update
D - Delete
M - Move
O - Copy
S - Sort
K - Rollback
P - Public Access
I - Manage Hostname
U - Publish
R - Permissions
Z - Audit Trail
:  - Edit in Canvas
5 - Send to translation
F - Browse Name
4 - Translate
H - Send To Publish